# How to refresh data inside VBox

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a XML view, and inside that, I have VBox.

```
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form">
    <VBox id="idIssuesItems">
        <Text text="Message1"></Text>
    </VBox> 
</mvc:View>
```

This view is used as reuse block in another object page. What I want is, When I click on a button in object page, I want that data inside VBox should get refreshed. How can I do that?

I tried doing this:

```
var aView = sap.ui.getCore().byId(sViewId);
 var vBoxData = aView.byId("idIssuesItems");
vBoxData.refresh(true);
```

However, it seems it's not working well.
For table, I can use this:

```
oSmartTable.rebindTable();
```

But I am not sure what can be done for VBOX.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you could get the model bound to `vBoxData` and refresh that directly perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `items` [aggregation from FlexBox](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.FlexBox/aggregations) which is the superclass of VBox.

```xml
<VBox id="idIssuesItems" items="{yourItemModel>/IssueItems}">
    <Text text="{yourItemModel>ItemText}"></Text>
</VBox>
```

Your model should look like this:

```js
var itemsModel = new JSONModel({
    IssueItems: [{
        ItemText: "Item 1 text!"
    }, {
        ItemText: "Item 2 text!"
    }, {
        ItemText: "Item 3 text!"
    }]
});

this.getView().setModel("yourItemModel", itemsModel);
```

Now every time you get a new `IssueItem` you can push this into the model after which the `VBox` automatically adds a new `Text` element:

```js
var yourNewIssue = {
    ItemText: "This is a new Issue"
};

var issueModel = this.getView().getModel("yourItemModel");
issueModel.getProperty("/IssueItems").push(yourNewIssue);
```